# How to use NI's VI in C#

Tags: c#, labview

I've  developed a project in LabVIEW. Now i need to convert the entire project into C#. I can convert all the VIs which is developed by me. But in my project i referred some of NI's VI for example`Get DAQ Device Information.vi` . How do i get the functionality inside thist VI. Or Does NI provide any dll for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a DLL provided for DAQmx. Follow the [instructions of NI](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/6C3024A6628FB629862575CC0079206A?OpenDocument) to get access to it.

Be sure to install the DAQmx driver. And, when you do be sure to add support for .NET

Comment: i've installed LabView 2009. I can not find `NI-DAQ»NI-DAQmx.NET Framework [version #] Help. ` . Where can i find this?

Comment: Try NI-DAQ»Text-Based Code Support»NI-DAQmx.NET Framework [version #] Help.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to install the DAQmx driver. And, when you do be sure to add support for .NET